# Create a customized page template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, custom, layouts

I am having a Wiki site in my SP 2013 on-premises environment. Each time we add a new page to the Wiki site, a page with the Basic Page layout is created. Then, in that page we create a table wit columns and rows.

The question is, to avoid creating the table each time, or copy paste it each time, is it possible to amend this (create new layout) page layout, so we always has the table added to the page layout when creating a new page in our Wiki site?

[image]

------------ UPDATE -------------

Thanks for the answers, they helped me some of the way, I am able to inser a simple HTML line. But have troubles for inserting a table.

What to implement in the aspx, if I want this tabel to be shown and editable in my custom page.

```
 <table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 703px;">​Jira Link</td>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 702px;">
           <br/>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​P no.</td>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​<span style="color: #333333; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​Date Created</td>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​Created By</td>
        <td class="ms-rteTable-default"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create page layout and upload to master page gallery and use it when ever and where ever you want.

Steps are bit lengthy so for clear picture i have pasted blog link for how to create page layout below.

Inside sharepoint site using sharepoint inbuilt features.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/03/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/644e54/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-share-point-2013-and-office-3/

Using visual studio

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/820508/step-by-step-creating-news-page-layout-using-conte

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-a-Page-Layout-(PageLayout)-with-ContentType-in-SharePoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

- Open SharePoint Designer > Connect to the Site Collection or Site where you require the new Page Layout.
- In the left menu of SharePoint Designer select Page Layouts > copy and paste the `EnterpriseWiki.aspx` page layout .
- Rename the file and its title, then right click and Edit in Advanced Mode.
- Make the changes you require and save. Check Out the file and then Check-In again.
- Now add the customised Page Layout by Going to Site Settings > Page Layout and Site Templates Setting.

[image]

For more details check [SharePoint – Customising the (Enterprise Wiki Page) basic page layout](https://baabaaconsulting.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/sharepoint-customising-the-enterprise-wiki-page-basic-page-layout/)

Comment: The changes, is it possible to insert "hardcoded" HTML in the page layput. Insted of the RichHTMLField, type my own HTML with a table content?

Comment: Yes its possible follow bellow links in answer you get to know how to achieve it.

Comment: yes you can customize and brand your page layout with your own HTML , follow this article to know how specifically you can brand your page layout with your own HTML without effect on the page layout http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Please see the latest update :).

Comment: @emo Let me please  apply this in my side and update you soon