# SP13: Wiki Page Template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, site-template, wiki

I have had no luck finding a solution without using SharePoint Designer.  I created a wiki page and would like to use it as a template over and over again.  I thought this would be simple as creating a template out of list by using the list settings.  I am not seeing the direct way of doing so for a wiki page.

Can I create a template from a wiki page?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to do the same thing on SharePoint online right now.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue. Anyone a update?

Comment: Yes: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201450/create-a-customized-page-template